# React history.push not working from the Home component

Tags: reactjs, forms, authentication, react-router, history.js

I'm implementing authentication to my React project and I'm trying to have the Login form in my Home component. This is how my Home component looks with the Login component attached to it.

```
import Login from './Login'
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Box sx={{
        width: 600,
        height: 150,
        backgroundColor: 'lightgrey',
        borderRadius: 16
      }}>
        {<h1>Welcome to our Podcast App</h1>}
        {<h2>Feel free to share your favorites or have fun listening to the ones available.</h2>}
      </Box><br/>
        < Login />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

The problem is, I want to redirect my users to the podcasts page and, `history.push` is not working. This is how the Login component looks.

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { loginUser } from "../actions/index";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import { Box } from "@material-ui/core";

class Login extends React.Component {
  state = {
    email: "",
    password: "",
    error: false
  };

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { email, password } = this.state;
    this.props
      .dispatchLoginUser({ email, password }) 
      .then(() => this.props.history.push('/podcasts')) 
      .catch(() => this.setState({ error: true }));   
  };
  

  render() {
    return (
      <Box sx={{ p: 2, border: '1px solid grey' }}>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
          <h3>Log In</h3>
          <p>{this.state.error && "Invalid email or password"}</p>
          <fieldset>
            <label htmlFor='email'>
              Email:
            </label>
            <input
              type='text'
              name='email'
              id='email'
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              value={this.state.email}
            />
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset>
            <label htmlFor='password'>
              Password:
            </label>
            <input
              type='password'
              name='password'
              id='password'
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              value={this.state.password}
            />
          </fieldset><br/>
          <Button variant="contained" size="small" color="inherit" type='submit'>Log In</Button>
        </form>
      </Box>
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    dispatchLoginUser: (credentials) => dispatch(loginUser(credentials))
  };
};

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
```

If I try to log in from the Login page, it will work. But it doesn't work from the Home page. I also tried adding history to my project like another post suggested but it still doesn't work. Here's the code:

```
//history.js
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export default createBrowserHistory();
```

```
//index.js
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

const history = createBrowserHistory();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={ store }>
    <Router history={history} >
      <App />
    </Router>
  </Provider>
```

```
//The routes in App.js
<Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
<Route exact path='/signup' component={Signup} />
<Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
```

Is it possible to make `history.push` work from the Home component? Any suggestion will be welcomed. Thank you all.

Comment: how about passing `history` props to `Login` from your `Home` component, like this `<Login history={this.props.history}/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to make history.push work from the Home component?

Yes, absolutely it is. You just need to destructure it from the `props` object in the `Home` component. For this the `Home` component needs to actually have a defined/declared `props` object.

```
const Home = (props) => {
  // access props.history
  return (
    ...
    <Login history={props.history} />
    ...
  );
};
```

or

```
const Home = ({ history }) => {
  // access history
  return (
    ...
    <Login history={history} />
    ...
  );
};
```

`Home` is a function component, so it can also use the `useHistory` hook and pass it along.

```
const Home = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  return (
    ...
    <Login history={history} />
    ...
  );
};
```

Comment: @Norbert Sorry, I neglected to mention that you could also decorate the `Login` component with the [withRouter](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) Higher Order Component to also have the `history` object injected as a prop, something like `connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(withRouter(Login))`. Otherwise, glad to help out. Cheers and good luck.

Answer (score 4):

In react-router-dom version 6
**useHistory()** is replaced by **useNavigate()**

```
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom'; 

const navigate = useNavigate(); 
navigate('/home')
```

Comment: You are right. I used useHistory(), but it's not worked.